# Solving $A\cosh(\alpha a)+B\sinh(\alpha a)=0$ and $-A\sinh(\alpha b)+B\cosh(\alpha b)=0$ for $A$ and $B$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Here im solving the PDE using the Variable and separable'

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=-v\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+D\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}$$

- initial conditions : $p(x,0)=\delta(x)$
- boundary conditions: $p(a,t)=0$, $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}|_{x=-b}=0$

I solved and finally got these equations:

$$\begin{align}
A\cosh(\alpha a)+B\sinh(\alpha a) &=0 \\
- A\sinh(\alpha b)+B\cosh(\alpha b) &=0
\end{align}$$

> How to solve for $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I have not gone through your calculation - But, the $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ are just constants and you have two equations and two unknowns. So you can solve for both.

Comment: The only solution is the trivial one. That's saying, I think, that you need to resolve the $p(x,0)=\delta(x)$ condition first. I imagine some sort of Fourier analysis would be required to get that delta function.